# $area Yielding odd results

Tags: qgis

I overlaid a 1600x1600 m grid on a city and clipped the grid to the boundaries. I am trying to get the area of each of the polygons, as the ones along the boundaries are going to be smaller. I'm using the field calculator and the $area command. I've tried using a couple of different fields - the integer and the decimal. The integer a) yields a negative number that is b) the same for all polygons and c)I don't think any of them are the right value. The decimal format yields a nan.

[image]

Comment: What CRS are you working with?

Comment: The km_integer issue looks to be a bug (-2.147B is `INT_MIN`)

Comment: What happens when you use *area($geometry)*?

Comment: @ChloeG NAD83/Indiana East

Comment: @StuSmith I think that might have done the trick. Haha. I was kind of gun shy because when I type it in the parentheses are highlighted so I thought that meant they were wrong.

Comment: Great!  FYI, I also use *length($geometry)* when working with linear data.